# how to pass the selected check box id of a input tag to views in django and bulk update the selected rows in table

Tags: django

**            1.how to pass the selected check box id of a input tag(which is in for loop, so the name and value of input tag are dynamic ) to views in django and bulk update the selected rows of  table in django**

```
<div class="jumbotron">

    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form|crispy}}

        <input  class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
<h3 > Model values </h3>
<ul>
<table class="table" id="tab1">
<thead>
{% if teams %}
    <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th><b>Logo</b> </th>
       <th><b> Team </b></th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    {% for value in models %}
    <tr>
        <td><input name="lol" type = "checkbox" value = "{{value.id}}"/> </td>
        <td>  {{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td> <img class="w3-display-topmiddle w3-container" src="{{ value.logUri.url }}" alt="alt txt" height="910" width="910"></td>

            <td>  {{   value.name }}  </td>


    </tr>

{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**realized that since i am not keeping input tag in form tag the input tag's name values is not captured by request.POST(now changes are dome in html as below ),later in django views i removed the unnecessary keysvalues using dict.pop() and created a list containing on primary keys
in django orm (model.filter(id__in= lst_of_id_captured).update(field='somevalue')  **

```
    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form|crispy}}
<h3 > Model values </h3>
<ul>
<table class="table" id="tab1">
<thead>
{% if teams %}
    <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th><b>Logo</b> </th>
       <th><b> Team </b></th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    {% for value in models %}
    <tr>
        <td><input name="lol" type = "checkbox" value = "{{value.id}}"/> </td>
        <td>  {{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td> <img class="w3-display-topmiddle w3-container" src="{{ value.logUri.url }}" alt="alt txt" height="910" width="910"></td>

            <td>  {{   value.name }}  </td>


    </tr>

{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>

        <input  class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```